# What's the number of minimum leaves in a binary tree?

Tags: binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm learning to use and Binary trees, and I want to understand it better.

Do we consider a root and a left node to that root to be a tree and consider it unbalanced? that will make the answer to be the number of minimal leaves in a tree to be 1. 
Otherwise if a tree needs 2 nodes under the root that will change the answer to the minimal leaves to be 2.

Comment: The minimal number of leaves in a binary tree is zero.

Comment: that doesn't sound right. Can you elaborate please. you mean that a tree can only have a root and the later is not even considered a leaf?

Comment: As @matt said, the minimum number of leaves in a tree is `0` if this tree is the empty tree (no nodes). Otherwise, for any number of nodes `n` there can be one leaf (the case where the tree is a branch).

Comment: Of course it sounds right. If it weren't, how could you ever construct the tree? You start with an empty tree. You start to add nodes. The tree doesn't say, "excuse me, you can't add nodes to me, I'm not a tree yet!" The empty tree _is_ a tree.

Answer (score -1):

The minimal number of leaves in a binary tree is zero